# After setting a condition in the alertcondition() it still sends short signals

Tags: pine-script

The condition I set was for the bot to buy when the price is above the 200 EMA and the supertrend line is green. However when I tested the bot it would trigger a short signal when the price was above the 200 EMA and the supertrend line was red. I want it to trigger a short signal ONLY when the price is below the 200 EMA and has a red supertrend line. Im new to Pine script so I don't know much.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Super Trend + EMA 2.0", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

len = input.int(200, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
out = ta.ema(src, len)
plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.blue)

atrPeriod = input(1, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(1, "Factor", step = 0.01)

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)

bodyMiddle = plot((open + close) / 2, display=display.none)
upTrend = plot(direction < 0 ? supertrend : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
downTrend = plot(direction < 0? na : supertrend, "Down Trend", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

fill(bodyMiddle, upTrend, color.new(color.green, 90), fillgaps=false)
fill(bodyMiddle, downTrend, color.new(color.red, 90), fillgaps=false)

alertcondition(close >= supertrend and out, title="Enter Long", message="MYAPIKEY")
alertcondition(close <= supertrend and out, title="Enter Short", message="MYAPIKEY")
alertcondition(close >= supertrend, title="Exit Short", message="MYAPIKEY")
alertcondition(close <= supertrend, title="Exit Long", message="MYAPIKEY")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the conditions used for `alertcondition()`. You need to compare the current close to the value of your EMA200 `out`. eg

`close >= supertrend and close > out`

However this will generate an alert for every bar that meets these conditions, ie every bar while price is above the supertrend and the ema. Most likely you will need to consider how to limit this.

For example only if the prior bar didn't meet these conditions.

```
long_condition = close >= supertrend and close > out
enter_long_condition = long_condition and not long_condition[1]
```

Comment: I have found a solution to the alert being generated every bar. Thank you for helping me with the 2 conditions not Being met too, all fixed.